# Linq: assign variables in Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq

when using the "from.. select" form I can assign local variables in Linq with the `let` statement. How to capture variables with lambdas? Non working example of what I need:

```
var result = list.Select(a =>
    let localVariable = a.number + 2 // <- obviously non working
    new {
        Variable = localVariable 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result = list.Select(a =>
  {
    var localVariable = a.number + 2;
    return new 
    {
        Variable = localVariable 
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: +1 Yep, just stick a ; on the end of "var localVariable = a.number + 2"

Comment: thanks i think this is what i'm looking for, but i get the following error:

A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: You didn't state you were using Linq on an IQueryable. What provider are you using? EF? Linq-to-sql? Or something else?